# accessing a pdf file using file upload

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I want to access a pdf file for the purpose of splitting it by using JFileChooser but PdfReader cannot read the file. The IOException reads "Publishing Letter.pdf not found as file or resource".

```
private void butSelectActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int returnValue  = fileChooserPdf.showOpenDialog(this);
    if(returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        int n;
        String theFile = fileChooserPdf.getSelectedFile().getName();
        String theFileInLower = theFile.toLowerCase();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Reading the file " + theFileInLower, "Ok", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        try
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(theFileInLower);
            n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
            System.out.println("there are " + Integer.toString(n) + " number of pages");
        }
        catch(IOException io)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, io.toString(), "Ok", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }

    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An error occured", "Ok", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }


}
```

Is it possible to access the pdf file by using the JfileChooser for the purpose of splitting it?, how would I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using the constructor with the file name. This way the file will be searched in the local dir. You should use the `InputStream` constructor with a `FileInputStream`. That way you will be able to pass directly the selected `File` object.